# Calculation order inside tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I tried to simplify the formula which calculates the angle

```
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle={20/100*360+30/100*360},center=M,radius=5cm] \tkzGetPoint{P}
```

by using

```
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle={(20+30)/100*360},center=M,radius=5cm] \tkzGetPoint{P}
```

but this throws an error. It seems that round brackets aren't allowed, are they? Any workaround?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle={(20+30)/100*360},center=M,radius=5cm] \tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzDrawCircle(M,P)
\tkzDrawPoint(P)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly which error do you get? This MWE compiles fine for me on TL2020.

Comment: @daleif I've just changed it.

Comment: It does give an error for me now. No idea why or how `tkz-euclide` parses math

Comment: With native tikz the calculation works just fine `\draw (5,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle={(20+30)/100*360},radius=5cm];`

Comment: From the manual it seems you need to do calculations separately via `xfp`, as in `\edef\tkzTest{\fpeval{(20+30)/100*360}}  
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=\tkzTest,center=M,radius=5cm] \tkzGetPoint{P}`